# How can I align slider, text and values?

Tags: html, css, slider

I am trying to align slider text, slider and readout value for 2 sliders.  My non-aligned attempt, using grid layout, is shown here: [image: non-aligned sliders]

And my relevant HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="rangeslider">
      <label for="tempo">Tempo    </label>
      <input type="range" min="10" max="100" value="30"
              class="myslider" id="tempo">
      <p>bpm: <span id="tempoOut"></span></p>
      <label for="duration">Duration</label>
      <input type="range" min="0.25" max="1" value="0.5" step="0.25"
              class="myslider" id="duration">
      <p>dur: <span id="durOut"></span></p>
   </div>


.myslider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: rgb(248, 212, 7)  ;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 2;
 } 
.myslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #34495E  ;
  width: 5%;
  height: 20px;
 }
 .myslider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I know I can do this with a table, but CSS would be better I think.

There is a repl [here](https://repl.it/@keble6/gridHTML) where you can see/try the full code.
Can anyone suggest a relatively simple method that works?

Comment: which type of alignment you want?

Comment: I want the sliders' left edge to be aligned (assuming they are both the same width). So that's like inserting a tab between the slider text and the slider itself.

Comment: I think margin-left solves your problem

Comment: Possibly, but I couldn't get what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I did get a solution with float: right;

```
.myslider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: rgb(248, 212, 7)  ;
  width: 70%;
  height: 5px;
  opacity: 2;
  float: right;
}
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]